# Check against multiple elements with one query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Is it possible to check multiple elements inside of a root using `where`? I have a XML sheet setup in such a way that there are multiple elements with the same name (but only sometimes), like so:

```
<person>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <food>orange</food>
    <food>apple</food>
</person>
<person>
    <name>Roger</name>
    <food>apple</food>
</person>
```

I want to be able to check whether or not a person has a specific type of food and then output them into console. Using this method to grab them from the XML sheet:

```
var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("person")
                    where (string)c.Element("food") == "apple" 
                    select new c.Element("food").Value;
```

It will only add Roger to the query. I believe this is because apple is second, since when I switch it to being first on the list I get Joe to show up. Is there a way to check to see if the second element meets the where statement as well?

Comment: `where (string)c.Element("food") == "apple"` is only checking the first element that matches *food*.

Comment: How would I check the second element that matches food, in addition to the first element?

Comment: enclose that xml with a root like <people>...your xml....</people>

Comment: I just left that out, it is enclosed once more though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out.It will return a projection with the name and food just to prove it has picked both:

```
var query = from c in xml.Root.Elements("person") //Descendants("person")
            from f in c.Descendants("food")
            where (string)f == "apple"
            select new { Food = f.Value,Name = c.Element("name").Value };
```

Output of query:

```
{Food = "apple", Name = "joe"}
{Food = "apple", Name = "Roger"}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to implement afterwards too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't add "Roger", but "apple" to the resulting IEnumerable. I assume you want to select the `name` element of your person.

As an alternative to the previous answer, you could also search for all apples and then get the name element of their parents.

```
var result = xml.Root.Descendants("food")
    .Where(x=> (string)x == "apple")
    .Select(y=> (string)y.Parent.Element("name"));
```

should do the trick

Comment: When I used `foreach` to check for names in the result, I got nothing.

Comment: See this DotNetFiddle Example https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qw8cor   The result is just an IEnumerable<string>

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda (short cutting since apple is hard coded):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root><person><name>Joe</name><food>orange</food><food>apple</food></person><person><name>Roger</name><food>apple</food></person></root>");

var results = doc.Root.Descendants("person")
 .Where(p => p.Elements("food").Any(f => f.Value == "apple"))
 .Select(p => "apple");
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oxJMin)